# Query conversion from sql server to ms access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

In my project i have to change my database from SQL server 2005 to MS access.But some of the queries are not working properly with MS Access.can anyone please convert the following query from sql to MS Access

```
SELECT l.id,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), l.app_date, 13), 1, 11), ' ', '/') AS app_date,
        l.reason,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), l.fromdate, 13), 1, 11), ' ', '/') AS fromdate,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), l.todate, 13), 1, 11), ' ', '/') AS todate,
        lt.LeaveDesc,
        l.noofdays,
        e.Abbv_name,
        e1.Abbv_name AS Expr1,
        l.Typeofleave AS Leave_ID
FROM leave AS l
INNER JOIN LeaveTypes AS lt
        ON l.Typeofleave = lt.TypeofLeave
LEFT JOIN Employee AS e1
        ON l.HRby = e1.Emp_id
LEFT JOIN Employee AS e
        ON l.approveby = e.Emp_id
WHERE l.submitby = 2
        AND submit = 'Y'
        AND approved IS NULL
```

In the above query leave is a table of my database.Thanks in advance...

Comment: What have you done ? SO is not a place to let others work for you. We can help you with specific questions if you have any.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.techonthenet.com very handy for understanding MS Access functions, you may also learn something that way too.

Answer (score 1):

The Access db engine requires parentheses in the `FROM` clause when you join more than 2 data sources.  Build your joins in Design View of the query designer.  It will add the parentheses the engine demands.  Off the top of my head, I think this revised `FROM` clause may work:

```
FROM ((leave AS l
INNER JOIN LeaveTypes AS lt
        ON l.Typeofleave = lt.TypeofLeave)
LEFT JOIN Employee AS e1
        ON l.HRby = e1.Emp_id)
LEFT JOIN Employee AS e
        ON l.approveby = e.Emp_id
```

If `app_date`, `fromdate`, and `todate` are Date/Time data type, you can use [Format()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx) expressions to return the date values as formatted strings.

```
SELECT Format(app_date, 'dd/mon/yyyy hh:nn:ss')
```

Comment: By answering his question you are encouraging bad posters to post bad questions.